# Bootstrapemail Gmail-mobile-webapp does not support `display: none`

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html-email, email-client

I use bootstrapemail to make my e-mails. But with I have problems with Gmail Mobile Webmail.
The user-icon must not be shown on mobile devices. But here it is shown in the logo in the header.

It doesn't respond to: `display: none;`. Also it ignores the `col-lg` classes of bootstrap-email when the header becomes to small. Can eneyone help me?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body class="bg-gray-200">
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Header Begin -->
        <div class="w-full p-4 bg-black">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <!-- Logo of Voetbalshop.nl -->
                <img class="h-12 ay-middle" src="#">
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-lg-2 ay-middle ax-right">
                <!-- User Icon redirect to login page of Voetbalshop.nl when clicked on -->
                <a class="no-underline" href="#">
                    <img class="w-7 d-none d-lg-inline ay-middle" src="#">
                </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Header End -->
```

In the image below tou can see what it looks like now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Display:none` is not supported on Gmail Mobile Webmail (but that's an extremely tiny percentage of people who use that - it is not the Gmail Mobile Apps): https://www.caniemail.com/clients/gmail/#mobile-webmail

It also doesn't support `<style>` blocks, along with Gmail IMAP (a type of Gmail account used a lot more): https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-style/. So since Bootstrap Email relies on @media queries in the `<style>` block for responsive behaviour, you won't be able to get responsive classes working in these clients (basically every other mobile client supports it).

You could try adding your own styles like `style="width:0;height:0;"` (inline on the image) and then adding a custom embedded style to show it in desktops like `<style>@media screen and (min-width:600px) {img .d-none {width:50px!important;height:50px!important;} }</style>`. (Caveat: there are a couple of less-used desktop applications that don't support the `<style>` block, and you'll have to do something about Outlook, but you can use their conditional block for that)

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try it. But one more question: doesn't bootstrap-email ignores my own style? I tried a couple of times to used my own styles. Or is it that you must override the bootstrap-email classes?

Comment: Sorry but bootstrap-email ignores my own styling. How can I solve this?

Comment: You can add you own, either inline or in a style block, but, it needs to match the rendered output, not the bootstrap code. The rendered output might be quite different. Does that solve it?

Comment: What do you mean with 'the rendered output'? and how can i make it different from bootstrap-email? Can you give an example?

Comment: And how do I kwow what to do?

Comment: It's the code when you click render